# What is the earliest example of "tops/at tops" for "at the most," and is it now more common outside of AmE?

Tags: word-usage, british-english, colloquialisms

The OED's entry and earliest citation for *tops* are:

> *plural* **tops** n. (also at tops) at the most, at the latest. Usually finally. *colloquial* (**originally and chiefly *U.S.***).
>
> **1956**   ‘B. Holiday’ & W. Dufty *Lady sings Blues* xii. 129   So she
> was only thirty-eight when she died. I'm going to do the same thing.
> I'm staying thirty-eight myself, maybe forty **tops**.

I don't see an OED citation illustrating "at the latest."

> **tops** adverb
>
> At the very most
>
> *will cost $50, tops* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tops)

> in American English
>
> *Slang*
> ADVERB
>
> At most
> *It'll take us a year, tops* [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/tops)

I was surprised to see that this informal meaning could be first documented only to 1956. Searching in Google Books for *tops* and *at tops* with this sense involves going through a lot hits for other meanings. In addition, it is used primarily in speech. However, I was able to find earlier examples (both reporting speech) including:

> "At least two-thirds of what I gave him was a loan, and the total was
> $4500 or $5000 **at tops,"** Mr. Gilbert said. [*Indianapolis Times,
> May 19, **1939***](https://newspapers.library.in.gov/cgi-bin/indiana?a=d&d=IPT19390519&e=-------en-20--1--txt-txIN-%22at%20tops%22------)

> Q. Nothing was said to Ancrum, is that right?
> A. It is only probably one minute from where we arrested him to the
> station house, maybe two **at tops**, at most.
> Q. You know you can say plenty in a minute or two—but nothing was said?
> A. Nothing was said.
> [*N.Y. Court of
> Appeals. Records and Briefs*, p.3631](https://www.google.com/books/edition/New_York_Court_of_Appeals_Records_and_Br/7Zzsufr-MI0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22at%20tops%22&pg=PA3631&printsec=frontcover) (**1941)**

This redundant "at tops, at most" *could* be the speaker's uncertainty about "at tops" being understood.

I'm interested in learning the current status of this informal *tops* outside the U.S., as well as earlier print examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDoS shows early usage from late ‘20s.  More recent examples are from AusE but the expression appears to be mainly used in AmE:

***[tops](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/fqufdbi)*** adv.
[SE at a top estimate]

> at the most, at the top estimate, e.g. five years tops, ten quid tops.

> 1928  [US]    J. O’Connor Broadway Racketeers 186: *The toughest rap ever registered brought, at tops, a six month’s bit.*
>
> 1938  [US]    D. Runyon *‘Pick the Winner’ in Runyon on Broadway (1954) 322: *The professor does not seem anxious to bet a sawbuck, tops.*

———-

> 2021  [Aus]   C. Hammer Opal Country 196: ‘*[T]en minutes tops’.*

Comment: Excellent. GDoS has "Midnight, tops," an example of *at the latest.* The OED's earliest struck me as quite late.